# Why is this answer considered spam?

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts, disputed-review-audits

I recently failed [this audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/18511085) in the Low Quality Posts queue and got banned.  Apparently, the community closed it as spam/abuse, although I still cannot figure out why.  It seems like a decent post to me.  My question is, why is [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/18511085) spam/abuse?  I am not asking to whine or complain, but I genuinely want to understand why so I can learn and become a better reviewer in the future.

I appreciate your assistance in helping me learn how to be a better reviewer.

**Edit**

For those who do not have the rep to view it through the link, below is  is a screen shot of the answer which which I incorrectly marked as "Looks Ok".  Of course, I did not have the benefit of seeing it was deleted by community during my review.  Here is the [link depicted in the screen shot](https://selenium-webdriver.com/java/robot-class-selenium-webdriver).

[image: Screenshot of Failed Audit]

Comment: A single failed audit will not trigger a ban, unless a moderator issued a manual ban, but I'd assume you'd be contacted privately and explained why.

Comment: 1. That is a good question.  2. It is not failing audits *in a row*.

Comment: You have three questions here on Meta.  They are all about failed audits.

Comment: Woa indeed... so this is your third failed audit since november 23rd 2017. Yes, a review ban sounds totally reasonable. You need to stop and think about your reviews.

Comment: I am not sure how my question history is relevant to understanding why the audit mentioned here is spam/abuse.  Not that it matters, but my other questions were well received with over 30 upvotes between them.  Still, my question and audit history aside, @Felix Gagnon-Grenier's point is valid.  I do need to think about my reviews.  That is why I asked this question.  I honestly do not understand why the answer linked in this question is spam/abuse.  I would really appreciate it if someone could enlighten me.  Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: @TomAranda, your edit helped the question quality, as it is now on point.  As I said in my earlier comment, this is good question.

Comment: @gnat I don't see any links in the post at all.

Comment: @Blackwood take a look at the [answer below](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/361921/839601), "The user in question

    posted almost nothing other than links to their site..."

Comment: @gnat I was referring to the post linked to from this Meta question. According to Ed's answer, the spammer's account has been deleted, but the account of the user who posted the linked question is still there. I can only assume that the post being discussed is actually a deleted answer that I can't see. Quite confusing.

Comment: @Blackwood and I refer to this guidance in the duplicate question: "To check this you'd need to go to poster's profile and verify... that other posts from this account do not advertise these links in a suspicious manner..." (performing this check would, besides just being correct course of action, also help OP pass this audit)

Comment: @gnat The user who posted the question linked to from this Meta question cannot be the user you and Ed are talking about as his account has not been deleted (and hist profile shows no questions containing links). I can only assume you are talking about some other user whose answer to that question has been deleted and which I therefore can't see. Not a problem but certainly confusing

Comment: @Blackwood sure we're talking about a user who posted the answer, under 10K rep you can see that audit was about this troublesome answer because audit page shows _answer not found_

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, here's a screenshot of the post for users with less than 10k rep:

[image]

This is not a great audit because it's not crystal-clear from that one post that it is spam. Audits are chosen automatically by the system, so sometimes audits aren’t obvious.

That said, the post *is* spam. The user in question

- posted almost nothing other than links to their site,
- was an alter ego for another account that had done the same thing, and
- had been warned repeatedly by ♦ moderators to stop.

Ultimately, we deleted the account entirely.

Comment: That makes much more sense.  I'm not sure how a reviewer is supposed to know all of that, but I do now understand why the answer was flagged as spam.  Thank you.

Comment: Added a little more to my post to clarify.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. It makes sense that this audit was chosen automatically.  To say it is not a great audit is an understatement.  I could not see a human picking it.  It is frustrating to fail a less-than-obvious audit, but it was time for me to take a break from SO anyway.  If there is a way for a moderator to remove this audit from system, I'd recommend doing so.  I would not like to see other reviewers get caught by it.

Comment: @EdCottrell Ehm this answer doesn't contain any links and seems like a normal answer. I understand the user was a spammer but the answer in question is by no means spam.

Comment: @EpicKip I’m not sure what you’re talking about. There’s a big, bold link on the very first line of that answer.

Comment: @EdCottrell -edit- Sorry, I'm a fool. I can't see the answer and had only seen the question... which looks fine of course.

Comment: @EpicKip ah, got it. I forgot that users with under 10k rep can’t see deleted answers in audits. I’ll try to add a screenshot for users with less than 10k rep.

Comment: @EpicKip Screenshot added.

Comment: @EdCottrell I take it that doesn't link where it says it does? The image clears up the answer, thanks :)